# How to output the results from 'for" loop in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have a code like that:

```
[X, Y, Z]= meshgrid(0:5:50, 0:5:50, 0:3:3);
[t1, t2, t3]= meshgrid(35, 25, 3);

A=sqrt((X - t1).^2 + (Y - t2).^2 + (Z - t3).^2);

[rows1,cols1,pages1] = ind2sub(size(A), find(A<=5));

for i=1:1:length(rows1);
    [R1, R2, R3]= meshgrid(cols1(i)*5-5, rows1(i)*5-5, pages1(i)*3-3);
    [reader]=[R1, R2, R3]

    B=sqrt((X1 - R1).^2 + (Y1 - R2).^2 + (Z1 - R3).^2);
    [rowsB,colsB,pagesB] = ind2sub(size(B), find(B<=5));

    for j=1:1:length(rowsB);
        [T1, T2, T3]= meshgrid(colsB(j)*0.2-0.2+0.15, rowsB(j)*0.2-0.2+0.15, pagesB(j)*3-3);
        [tag]=[T1, T2, T3];
    end
end
```

I need to have all the results from "for" loop because need to apply "intersec" on these results. But i'm facing problem because "for" overwrite the results and i take only the last. How to make smth like

```
[tag(i)]=[T1, T2, T3] where i is i=1:1:length(rows1).
```

I have applied smth with pre-allocation but is not working.

Answer (score 2):

In general you could use cell arrays:

```
tag = cell(length(rows1),1);
for i=1:length(rows1)
    tag{i} = [T1, T2, T3];
end
```

Though it looks like a simple matrix would do..

Answer (score 0):

In order to assign vectors to rows of a matrix, you will need to slice across columns using a colon for the column index.  Something like this:

```
tag = zeros(length(rows1), 3);
for i = 1:length(rows1)
    ...
    tag(i, :) = [T1, T2, T3];
end
```

edit: Fixed my example.  I misread your code.  The above is more general.